# Java Mailing API - To address

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send email from `Java` using Java mail APIs in `Eclipse` and it is working fine if I give the full email address in the TO address. But I could see in outlook and all if i give the user id (8 character length ) and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, it is changed to email address.

So is there any facility by which we can give user id in the TO address column which will be mapped to the corresponding email id ?

Comment: Are you looking for this in eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you want functionality you want to implement in your application, and is unlikely to be provided by the `javax.mail` API.

I imagine the basic approach would be to store all the possible email addresses within your application, and then when triggered (either by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> or some other means) a lookup is performed to determine if any addresses uniquely match the input. If so, use that email address, if multiple matches are found determine which one the user wants, and if none are found let the user know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to map recipient email address with user id :

> InternetAddress fromAddress=new InternetAddress(from,"user_id");

In upper code **user_id** is email address alias.

After this your client application i.e. Outlook might will use this user id  for **ctrl + k** functionality.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is a lookup from a user directory like LDAP or AD. This is not possible with the Java mail API.

If such directory system exists with user id's and emails, then you can perform a lookup before setting the email address. You can utilise libraries such as OpenLDAP to do the lookup.